# C++ Development For iPhone

Tags: iphone

I know about http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm but is there other tools that I can use to write C++ for iPhone? Is there a book maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use c++ for iPhone development - this might help:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cpp/c-on-iphone-part-1.html

Alternatively, just learn Objective-C it's nice :)

Answer (score 2):

For sake of updating this thread, here are some great tools I'm learning now to be able to build iPhone games using C++ that can be cross-deployed to Android, Mac, Windows, etc:

- Cocos2d-x: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/
- Cocos2d-x tutorial: http://paralaxer.com/cocos2d-x-tutorial/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for more ways to avoid using a mac and xcode, or just other c++ tools?

For the latter, almost any c or c++ library will work.  Basically you can embed c++ objects in your objective-c objects and make use of them.  Apple calls mixing c++ with objective-c  objective-c++: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html